# How to share Directus project?

Tags: node.js, directus, headless-cms

I'm currently running Directus project and PostgreSQL database on localhost and everything works fine. For now, I have to share this project with another person, but in the source folder of the project there are no generated files that I can share, so I assume everything is saved in node_modules. How to correctly share the project or push it into GitHub?

**Directus version: 9.9.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you need to share an instance of Directus is in the database, within the asset storage (folder), the `.env` file, and any custom extensions you've created. Hopefully, that helps!